# On changing device font, app font changes.How to restrict that?

Tags: react-native, text, fonts, size

I have used one custom font in the react native application. And everything is working fine accept when the users go to the phone settings and change the font size. Then in the application the UI looks pretty ugly. I have used StyleSheet.create method to create all the styles in the app and also have given definite font sizes for the texts. But even though when the phone settings font size is changed, my app font size also changes.

Is there a way to restrict any changes in the app's font size, irrespective of what users may do in the phone settings?

Comment: did you have mention `fontFamily` for every `Text` style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem using the following code in every page

```
constructor() {
    super();
    if (Text.defaultProps == null) Text.defaultProps = {};
       Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
}
```

Hope it can help others as well.

Answer (score 7):

Or you can add this in your main app index.js file

```js
// Override Text scaling
if (Text.defaultProps) {
  Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
} else {
  Text.defaultProps = {};
  Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
}

// Override Text scaling in input fields
if (TextInput.defaultProps) {
  TextInput.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
} else {
  TextInput.defaultProps = {};
  TextInput.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can stop the scaling with this prop allowFontScaling={false} in your Text component.

Ref - https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#allowfontscaling

Comment: But it is not working with custom font. My requirement is if I set the font size to let say 12, then even if we go to the phone settings and change the device font size, it should not change. @dhruv soni

Comment: I had the same issue and I have used this prop to achieve the same. It has always worked for me. Can you please post your Text component here? And Some other details like your device type it is Android or iOS. And OS versions as well

Answer (score 1):

For projects using functional components and hook,
Add below line in useEffect of App.js file

```
if (Text.defaultProps == null) Text.defaultProps = {};
       Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
```